# Can not hide bottom tab navigation ReactNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hi I have a bottom tab bar navigation and inside one tab I have stack navigator  I want to hide this navigation for specific screens

BottomTabBar:

```
   --Tab 1 
   --Tab 2
   --Tab 3: 
          -- Page 1 (I want to have bottom bar here)
          -- Page 2 (I don't want to see bottom bar navigation)
          -- Page 3 (I don't want to see bottom bar navigation)
   --Tab 4
   ....
```

the first problem is Page 2 and Page 3 shouldn't have tab bar (there is a back button to Page 1)

And the second problem is when I am in Tab 3 on Page 2 or Page 3 and click on Tab 1 and then back to Tab 3 I still see Page 2 or 3 and I need to reset stack to Page 1 every time when I will come to tab 3

This is main bottom tab bar  navigator

```
...
const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator();

...


 return (
    <BackgroundSafeAreaView>
      <Navigator tabBar={(props) => <Navigation {...props} />}>

        <Screen
          component={SupportScreen}
          name="Support"
          options={{ title: 'Support', tabBarAccessibilityLabel: I18n.t('accessibility.navigation.supportTab') }}
        />
        <Screen
          component={SettingsNavigator}
          name="Settings"
          options={{
            title: 'Settings',
            tabBarAccessibilityLabel: I18n.t('accessibility.navigation.settingsTab'),
            tabBarVisible: true,
          }}
        />
      </Navigator>
    </BackgroundSafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

I and here is Settings (Tab 3), navigator:

```
const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

const SettingsNavigator = () => (
  <Navigator initialRouteName="Settings" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Screen component={SettingsScreen} name="Settings" />
    <Screen component={SignUpScreen} name="SignIn" />
    <Screen component={SetPasswordScreen} name="ChangePassword" />
  </Navigator>
);

export default SettingsNavigator;
```

I tried a lot of stuff but I can not hide that navigation and `tabBarVisible: true` doesn't hide that navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [Hiding tab bar in specific screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/)?

In your case, it may look like:

```js
// TabNavigator.js
...
const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator();

...


 return (
    <BackgroundSafeAreaView>
      <Navigator tabBar={(props) => <Navigation {...props} />}>

        <Screen
          component={SupportScreen}
          name="Support"
          options={{ title: 'Support', tabBarAccessibilityLabel: I18n.t('accessibility.navigation.supportTab') }}
        />
        <Screen
          component={Settings}
          name="Settings"
          options={{
            title: 'Settings',
            tabBarAccessibilityLabel: I18n.t('accessibility.navigation.settingsTab'),
            tabBarVisible: true,
          }}
        />
      </Navigator>
    </BackgroundSafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

```js
const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

const SettingsNavigator = () => (
  <Navigator initialRouteName="Settings" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    {/* Here use the Tavigator instead of Settings screen */}
    <Screen component={TabNavigator} name="Settings" />
    <Screen component={SignUpScreen} name="SignIn" />
    <Screen component={SetPasswordScreen} name="ChangePassword" />
  </Navigator>
);

export default SettingsNavigator;
```

Comment: you set me on the right path... it works right now .. thx